# Implementing infinite scrolling on React Native's scrollview

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I'm trying to implement infinite-scroll approach for my feed items. I'm using scrollview for the feed container and MobX store for the data array.

I can detect onEndReached on my scrollview, but I've no idea how to append the more feed items to the scrollview.

How to achieve that? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can help from here. https://blog.nativebase.io/building-infinite-scroll-in-react-native-e717602553f8. This is a nice article regarding what you need.

Comment: @arun-k Thanks, I'm already read it before, but got some stucks on combining my dataset in MobX store with the impagination dataset.